# QMetaObject::invokeMethod is not called in the correct thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, signal-processing, signals-slots, event-loop

Given the following:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
      Q_OBJECT

   public:

      void run() override
      {
         qDebug() << "Started thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
         exec();
      }

   public slots:

      void someSlot()
      {
         qDebug() << "Slot called from thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
      }
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Main thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();

    MyThread t;
    t.start();

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&t, "someSlot", Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return app.exec();
}
```

I will get the following output:

```
Main thread:  0x7fc24e2f3780
Started thread:  0x7fc245493700
Slot called from thread:  0x7fc24e2f3780
```

However, due to `Qt::QueuedConnection` & the event loop running in the instance of `MyThread`, I would expect the slot being executed in `0x7fc245493700`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QThread` objects lives in the main thread, i.e. the thread that created the object, not in the thread it represents. This is explicitly stated in the Qt doc (but follows the normal 'living'-rules) [[1]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details):

> It is important to remember that a `QThread` instance lives in the old
> thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run().
> This means that all of `QThread`'s queued slots and invoked methods will
> execute in the old thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke
> slots in the new thread must use the worker-object approach; new slots
> should not be implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.

Please check the [`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) docs for an example of this worker-object approach.

Note that `Qt::QueuedConnection` is irrelevant, as it will be automatically queued when caller and slot lives in different threads[[2]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> `Qt::AutoConnection` **(Default)** If the receiver lives in the thread
> that emits the signal, `Qt::DirectConnection` is used. Otherwise,
> `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used. The connection type is determined when
> the signal is emitted.

Comment: Okay wow, didn't expect this. So its not possible to subclass `QThread` and have the logic implemented in the subclass? Its a bit cumbersome if you always need a dedicated `QThread` instance next to the object containing the logic. I was already able to solve this in this way yesterday, as I also found the worker example, however I didn't like the approach so well, so I was trying to find a cleaner approach.
For the connection type: as stated, this will get determined upon signal delivery, and I wanted to cut this small overhead by "forcing" the correct type beforehand.

Comment: You can try to combine the Controller and Worker in a single class. So, everything is implemented in a single class (you do not need to subclass QThread). You may also be interested in the high level [`QtConcurrent::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html)